# Java= arbitrary placement of if statement gives different output?

Tags: java, string, if-statement

I am goofing around in CodingBat with Java Strings warm-ups.

The prompt was:

*Given a string, return the count of the number of times that a substring length 2 appears in the string and also as the last 2 chars of the string, so "hixxxhi" yields 1 (we won't count the end substring).*

*last2("hixxhi") → 1*

*last2("xaxxaxaxx") → 1*

*last2("axxxaaxx") → 2*

My first attempt was:

```
public int last2(String str) {

   String last = str.substring(str.length()-2);
   int count = 0;

   if (str.length() < 2){
      return 0;
   }


   for (int i = 0; i <str.length()-2; i++){
      String sub = str.substring(i,i+2);

      if (sub.equals(last)){
         count++;
      }
    }

return count;

}
```

This code produced the correct output for all tests except when the input string had a length less than 2 (output = `Exception:java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1 (line number:3)`, etc.), meaning the `if` statement was ignored.

[image]

However, simply moving the `if` statement above the variable declarations in the beginning of the method made the code correctly pass all tests (even strings with length less than two):

```
public int last2(String str) {

   if (str.length() < 2){
     return 0;
   }

  String last = str.substring(str.length()-2);
  int count = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i <str.length()-2; i++){
      String sub = str.substring(i,i+2);

      if (sub.equals(last)){
        count++;
       }
    }

    return count;

  }
```

[image: Output for attempt 1]

I feel like the variable declarations shouldn't have any impact on the functionality of the `if` statement... what is keeping my first coding attempt from working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first snippet `String last = str.substring(str.length()-2);` would throw an exception when `str.length < 2`, so the if statement didn't get executed at all.

In your second snippet you placed the if statement in the correct location.

Comment: Oh duh. You get the answer in 12 minutes :)